# OpenCL build failed on AMD R9 290 - Insufficient Private Resources

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, opencl

I'm running Blender on windows. Recently I tried to use GPU rendering with my AMD R9 290, but upon rendering, I get an error reading "OpenCL build failed: error in console."

Meanwhile, in the console:

```
Device init success
Compiling OpenCL kernel ...
Build flags:
OpenCL kernel build output:
Error:E013:Insufficient Private Resources

OpenCL build failed: errors in console
```

CPU rendering works fine.

I'm running Windows 8. Driver version is Catalyst 14.4.

Comment: Are you running out of memory?

Comment: I don't think so. I've got another good 11GB of RAM it can use. As for the video memory, I don't know for certain, but there's nothing serious loaded and I get the same error with an empty scene with just a cube, light and a camera.

Comment: have you tried using blender version 2.75?

Comment: Yup. Running 2.75a.

Comment: Sounds like you might want to try a [report to the tracker](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/create/?project=2&type=Bug)

Comment: I opened a ticket. Will report back if it's of any use

Answer (score 1):

The solution is the update the drivers. Version 15.07 works fine with 2.75a.